# Xcode Cloud Fails to export archive: Command exited with non-zero exit-code: 70

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-cloud

I'm using Xcode Version 13.4.1. I have a project that builds an iOS app successfully in Xcode cloud. However, I am getting errors when trying to execute the archiving action.

It seems archiving for app-store distribution works but fails archiving for development distribution and ad-hoc distribution. I only need the archive for app-store distribution and so what is the way to disable archiving for the other two ?

Run command: 'set -o pipefail && source /Volumes/Task/ci_build.env && source /Volumes/Task/ci_plan.env && xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Volumes/workspace/tmp/14d7cc6f-0bff-4ee0-9b29-a3498449ac5f.xcarchive -exportPath /Volumes/workspace/developmentexport -exportOptionsPlist /Volumes/workspace/ci/development-exportoptions.plist '-DVTPortalRequest.Endpoint=http://172.16.117.70:8089' -DVTProvisioningIsManaged=YES -IDEDistributionLogDirectory=/Volumes/Task/logs/development-export-archive-logs -DVTSkipCertificateValidityCheck=YES -DVTServicesLogLevel=3 2>&1 | tee /Volumes/Task/logs/development-export-archive-logs/xcodebuild-export-archive.log'

Run command: 'set -o pipefail && source /Volumes/Task/ci_build.env && source /Volumes/Task/ci_plan.env && xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Volumes/workspace/tmp/09445e9e-07e2-4c99-a4ad-034a1c92c652.xcarchive -exportPath /Volumes/workspace/adhocexport -exportOptionsPlist /Volumes/workspace/ci/ad-hoc-exportoptions.plist '-DVTPortalRequest.Endpoint=http://172.16.117.70:8089' -DVTProvisioningIsManaged=YES -IDEDistributionLogDirectory=/Volumes/Task/logs/ad-hoc-export-archive-logs -DVTSkipCertificateValidityCheck=YES -DVTServicesLogLevel=3 2>&1 | tee /Volumes/Task/logs/ad-hoc-export-archive-logs/xcodebuild-export-archive.log'

Also, is there any way to provide a custom export options plist ?[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILjvg.png)